# How to debug email failure (Codeigniter/PHP)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am unable to send email using Codeigniter 3.0 's Email library.
No errors and nothing returned. Even `$this->email->print_debugger()` returns nothing.
So I also tried using PHP's native `mail()` function but that did not work as well.
I am using the configuration provided by my hosting provider in following format -

```
Outgoing server: xxxxx.xxxx.net
SMTP Port: 465 
Username: <account username>
Password: <account password>
```

I can send email using a mail client configured using the same configuration.
My question is - How do i debug this?

Here is my controller code -

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'xxxx.xxxx.net';
    $config['smtp_user'] = '<username>';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '<password>';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('<from-address>');
    $this->email->to('<to-address>');
    $this->email->subject('Test email');
    $this->email->message('Test email');
    if(!$this->email->send()){
        print_r($this->email->print_debugger(), true);
    }
```

I am on Apache server.

What have I tried so far -

1. Changing protocol to 'mail'
2. Working with SSL and Non-SSL settings

Comment: Can you please add your controller code for that to your question you have email. And what are you using for localhost wamp, xampp etc.

Comment: I have added the controller code. I am running on an Apache server.

Comment: wait what is this code:  $this->email->from('<from-address>'); ??? have you tried it with real email addresses?

Comment: @cartalot yes i have tried it with real email addresses. I am just masking private information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct. The hosting provider has setup filters on smtp such that only email addresses having domain names registered with them will be processed.

There is no way to debug this other than talking it out with the hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
log_message('debug', 'Some Text here');
```

This will print error message.

Better you use phpmailer. So it will print debug report by default

Comment: log_message() has not helped. I could not find this in the official documentation, what am i missing?

Comment: Use phpmailer library. Its easy to use and having more functionelty